# Laravel 5.2 Mutators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Mutator in laravel 5.2

```
public function setDateOrderAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['date_order'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}
```

It works if I created a record, but I if update it doesn't work.

I use Mass Assignment in both cases.

Another think..
If I put a `dd($value);` in create I see the output, but in update, nothing.

What I miss?

Thankss

Comment: can you add your two methods to your question (update and create).

Answer (score 0):

clue from laravel 5.2 docs

> This mutator will be automatically called when we attempt to set the value of the first_name attribute on the model:

Maybe you didn't trigger the field's update like

```
$Eloquent->DateOrder=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2016-10-12'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your update array and make sure that you have 'date_order' in that array.